# How to implement dataTables for dynamic data in Angular 10?

Tags: angular, datatable, datatables, angular10

For example, I have created a shared Table component and, I am passing the headers array with the data source to display the data on the table accordingly.
How can I achieve this using data Tables?

//Code HTML

```
 <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row- 
   border hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" *ngFor="let t of tableHeaders;index as i">
          {{t.display}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let rep of data">
        <td *ngFor="let t of tableHeaders">
          {{rep[t.key] ? rep[t.key] : '-'}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

// ts

```
 @Input() dataSource: any;
 @Input() tableHeaders: any[];
 public data : any;
 public dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
 public dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit() {
this.data = this.dataSource;
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  responsive: true,
  pageLength: 10
};
this.dtTrigger.next();
}

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.dtTrigger.next();
 }
```

Comment: Please give some code so we can help you

Comment: @LotteLemmens i have updated a basic code.please check.

Comment: In the onchanges, check if you have values in you dataSource. If so, you'll have to map them to your tableHeaders

Comment: just checked,datatable working fine for small data, but for large data , it takes time and displays all array elements at once instead of paginated data table.